# ImageMagick @filename referencing with multiple outputs

Tags: powershell, imagemagick

I see in ImageMagick's documentation that I can use something like `magick @myfiles.txt` to send multiple filenames (in my case I can't use globbing since they're random) to input, but the only example available combines them into a single output.

Is there a way to output separate files for each input using this functionality? If not, how would one achieve this in Powershell? Something like `Get-content filenames.txt | ForEach-Object {magick}`?

Comment: I don't know Powershell either, but you'd probably want something like `Get-content filenames.txt | ForEach-Object magick THISOBJECT some processing OUTPUTFILENAME` where the things in upper case are Powershell ways of referring to objects...

Comment: ```Get-Content filenames.txt | ForEach-Object {magick _$ -set filename:fn "%t" -quality 100 -format jpg ./fullsize/%[filename:fn].jpg"}``` did the trick. It converts the filenames it can find and doesn't break with the missing ones, unlike imagemagick itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this so make a **COPY** of a few files in a temporary directory before trying.

Make an output directory called `RESULTS` and resize a bunch of files listed in `files.txt`

```
mkdir RESULTS
magick mogrify -resize 64x64 -path RESULTS @files.txt
```

Be very careful with `mogrify`, if you don't specify `-path` it will overwrite a lot of files very, very quickly.

Comment: won't ```mogrify``` overwrite the original files rather than outputting new ones?

Comment: That's what `-path` is for... to specify the output path.

Comment: for two different outputs that would be ```magick mogrify -resize 1000x1000 -format jpg -path RESIZED -format jpg -path FULL_SIZE @files.txt```? Or do I need to use ```-write```?

Comment: Yikes! I doubt `-write` will honour the `-path` and also whether `mogrify` is the correct tool if you want multiple output files from one input file. I think you'll need to use Fred's (fmw42) answer and generate the big file first and `-write` it, then `-resize` and the name of the smaller file. Or use my answer twice - once for each size.

Comment: Maybe update your question to better reflect your aims too... thanks.

Comment: Using your answer twice seems good enough to me, but now I ran into another issue. Not all files in ```files.txt``` exist in the folder, can I tell imagemagick to skip those rather than break? Sorry for the long thread, but all imagemagick's forum pages seem to be offline...

Answer (score 2):

If your ImageMagick command is simple and just one image in the command line, then you can use magick mogrify to process each image in the folder. Otherwise, you can use -set filename to use the file names for multiple input/output images in a magick command line. However, if you have too many input images, then you will run out of RAM, since ImageMagick loads all the input images at one time in the magick command. magick mogrify reads them one at a time. For a magick command, you can do

```
magick @myfiles.txt -set filename:fn "%t" <commands> +adjoin "%[filename:fn]_processed.suffix"
```

The %t gets the name of the file without the suffix.  See https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php

Also see mogrify at https://archive.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify

Sorry, I do not know Powershell.

Comment: I'm dealing with thousands of tiffs so would most definitely run into the RAM issue. ```mogrify``` with specified ```-path``` solved my problem

Comment: When using ```magick file -set filename:fn "%t" -quality 100 -format jpg -write ./jpeg-hd/%[filename:fn].jpg -resize 1000x1000 ./jpeg-sd/%[filename:fn].jpg``` does the second jpg get saved from the input tif or from the compressed ```-write``` output?

Comment: The output comes from whatever processing you do to the input all the way to the end. The write only saves the input processed up to that point. The write does not change what is seen as processing after it. So the output of your command would be the same as not have put in the -write xxx.jpg

Comment: so -write and +write are not that different after all. I thought +write would roll back to the input data before any processing

Comment: No any processing done before +write that changes pixels will still affect the +write result. It just does not do any of the subsequent processing. It is like saving an intermediate result from the processing so far. It is useful for debugging by looking at each step of the processing.